# How Can I Retrieve All XmlEntityReference Objects In An XmlDocument Object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I have a number of xml documents from which I want to retrieve all of the entity references and perform some updates on the documents. I am using an XmlDocument object to do the updates. What is the best way to retrieve all entity references from an XmlDocument object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best or most efficient solution, but in light of the fact that I did not receive any other answers, this is what I came up with:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
reader.EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandCharEntities;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);

List<XmlEntityReference> entityRefs = new List<XmlEntityReference>();
RetrieveEntityRefs(doc.DocumentElement, doc, entityRefs);

private void RetrieveEntityRefs(XmlNode parentNode, XmlDocument doc, List<XmlEntityReference> entityReferences) {
    foreach (XmlNode node in parentNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EntityReference) {
            XmlEntityReference entityRef = node as XmlEntityReference;
            entityReferences.Add(entityRef);
        }
        else if (node.HasChildNodes) {
            RetrieveEntityRefs(node, doc, entityReferences);
        }
    }
}
```